# Warning for text box when characters nearning limit

Tags: javascript, jsp

Currently the warning only appears when the page has been saved i was wondering if the warning could appear as the user is typing it and it gets to below 15.

c:if test="${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH-fn:length(status.value) < 15}">

div class="warning notice text-content mt0">

Warning: The response entered is nearing the maximum character count.

```
/div>

/c:if>
```

Comment: Search for javascript character counter...in form field

Comment: I have the counter working its a warning when it gets bellow a certain amount to occur as the user types not how to code a character counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
var max =100;
            var warning = 5;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('body').on('keydown','textarea',function(){
                    if($('#textarea').val().length>=warning){
                        $('label').html(max-$('textarea').val().length+' characters left');
                    }else{
                        $('label').html('');
                    }
                });
            });
```